# Disabling an old tractor by removing magneto cap end, am I risking damage?

Tags: ignition, tractor

I purchased an old (Allis Chalmers WD45) tractor which I am storing at a remote but accessible location. This tractor is magneto fired and can be hand cranked to start as well as started with a 6v battery/starter setup.

There are no security features at all so anyone with physical access to the tractor can start it.

In order to secure the tractor against easy theft, I decided to mark my ignition cables and pull the cap end (looks like a small distributor) off the magneto. I covered the exposed end of the magneto with tightly sealed aluminum tape and bagged the exposed cable ends.

Am I risking any kind of damage to the cap, magneto, or cables (or other issues) if I do this on regular basis?

Comment: I think the only thing you'd be risking is water ingress into the magneto body. I'll try to do some research and see if there might be a better solution for you ... I was thinking you might be able to have a "part time" ground to the magneto output. So, if you flipped an inconspicuous switch somewhere, it would go closed and all electricity would flow out to ground instead of going out to the "distributor" ... something simple, but less conspicuous than a missing cap.

Comment: Thanks @paulster2, moisture penetration was my guess as a main risk.  Would water in the magneto cause permanent/long term problems, or would it just be a problem until dry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you are going to run into is condensation or water infiltration into the magneto, which will cause rust and possibly other issue down the road. There should be a set of points or some other way inside which causes the magneto to fire. This could get damage from the moisture. Secondarily, what you're doing is very easily seen as the "problem" and can be overcome by just getting a spare to replace the missing part.

A better way to do this (as I stated in the comments) may be to disable it through the use of a hidden switch. It then becomes problematic for whomever may be trying to take the tractor to get it started and going, which makes it a little more less likely to be stolen.

Currently, your system should have a way to shut off the engine so it doesn't run forever. This is your "key". To make it work, add a 2nd switch inline with the wiring going to this "key". It can be before or after the "key", but needs to be out of sight and as hard to get to as you are comfortable with switching every time you go to start the tractor. Both of these switches (key and newly introduced switch) have to be in the on position before you can fire the tractor.

Another thing to think about is how easy it would be to back a rollback up to the tractor and just winch it up onto the back of it. You could easily do this with or without the tractor running. You need to be able to make it so it won't roll either, or you're not going to have a tractor very long.

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: Thanks Paulster, all good points.  Luckily in my case the storage location for the tractor makes moving it without starting it a real headache, it has implements on the front and back which are lowered to the ground, you need the hydraulics running to lift them and it's tucked between large trees down a narrow wooded lane.  But I definitely don't want to mess up the magneto as it was just recently rebuilt.